# How Does input Buffer actually works in C++?

Tags: c++, input-buffer

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    int age, Rollno;
    cin >> age;
    cin >> Rollno;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << name << " " << age << " " << Rollno;
}
```

After entering a value for `age` using `cin`, a newline character remains in the input buffer. Despite this, how does the subsequent `cin >>Rollno;` successfully read the input for `Rollno` without any issues? Additionally, why is `cin.ignore();` necessary before using `getline(cin, name);`  and not necessary before `cin>>Rollno;` in this code?

Comment: `operator>>(int&)` is defined to skip leading whitespace. The `\n` character left behind in the buffer after `cin>>age` is whitespace, and is thus skipped. Whereas `getline` doesn't skip leading whitespace.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "*`operator>>(int&)` is defined to skip leading whitespace*" - unless `>> noskipws` (ie `cin.unsetf(skipws)`) is used beforehand, that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the parsers for `cin` (such as the one that looks for integers, as you're using) will happily ignore leading whitespace, and this includes vertical whitespace like `\n`. `getline` is not a parser; it simply gives you raw information without looking at it, so it has no such luxury.

Suppose our input is `3\n4\nBob\n`. Then we run your code.

```
cin >> age;
```

The input buffer starts with a number, so we read `3`. Then we leave `\n4\nBob\n` in the buffer.

```
cin >> Rollno;
```

Ignore leading whitespace (the newline) to get `4\nBob\n`. Now we see a number, so we read `4` and leave `\nBob\n`.

At this point, using `cin.getline` would be a mistake, as we would read only the newline character and then stop. So instead we

```
cin.ignore();
```

This ignores one character and leaves `Bob\n` in the buffer.

```
getline(cin, name);
```

Now we read a line until we hit `\n`. We consume the `\n` but do not store it. So `name` gets the value `"Bob"` and the input buffer is now empty.

Answer (score 1):

When using the [FormattedInputfunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) `basic_istream& operator>>( int& value )`, it will extract an `int` and will by default skip any preceding whitespaces. That's part of what the formatted input functions do.

> why is `cin.ignore();` necessary before using `getline(cin, name);`

`std::getline` is an [UnformattedInputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction) which will not skip whitespaces.

Mixing formatted and unformatted input often leads to problems so either stick to one or the other or you'll have to manually deal with lingering characters after formatted input when you switch to unformatted input.